# Send progress of CloudPage back to browser during AJAX request

Tags: marketing-cloud, javascript, ampscript, ssjs, ajax

I'm processing CSV files with a CloudPage. I upload the CSV file, then stringify the array, and send it via AJAX to another page. Previously, I had been doing this row by row so that I could show a progress bar and update it with a percentage every row. But this is too slow, so I want to send all of the data at once. (I realize this may cause a timeout, but that's a separate issue).

So if I send all of the data, how can I get feedback to the client side while the server side is processing? I have found some examples of using XHR https://coderwall.com/p/je3uww/get-progress-of-an-ajax-request but it looks like that only works for image uploads and downloads. I imagine there may be something I can place on my AmpScript processing page so send feedback back to the client side, but I'm not sure what that would be. I'm less familiar with SSJS, so perhaps there's something there. Or maybe this isn't possible.

As a fallback, I could just chunk the data into 50 rows at a time which would allow me to still have my progress bar.

Another thought is to use PHP and Heroku for this, but then I'm concerned about hitting API limits and I'm not sure it will be any faster.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge, there is no progress capability for bulk import/upsert/update as it does the upload on server-side (before anything is passed back in a response), so its really only pass/fail that is possible to be sent back and nothing incremental without you making it incremental in your requests.

A pretty garbage option/alternative could be to count the average time it takes for you to upload a record in bulk uploads and then use that as a calculation in your progress bar to show a guesstimate of the progress. It would be 100% fake and a complete guess, but it could help give something pretty for your users to look at and get an idea of how far along it is in general.

Comment: Thanks @Gortonington, yeah maybe I'll do the fake progress bar. It's ugly, but at least gives the user feedback that things are still moving. I'll probably chunk it up into separate requests as well.